# how to find all many to many objects for parent of parent object in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following object structure:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Customer Name', max_length=64)

class Location(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, blank=True, null=True)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Group Name', max_length=64)
```

How do I find all of the unique Group objects for a Customer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `customer` object,

```
groups = Group.objects.filter(location__customer = customer).distinct()
```

Documentation on [lookups across relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)